# Adding a new row to a dataframe with correct mapping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe something like below-

```
      carrier_plan_identifier           ...            hios_issuer_identifier
1                        AUSK           ...                           99806.0
2                        AUSM           ...                           99806.0
3                        AUSN           ...                           99806.0
4                        AUSS           ...                           99806.0
5                        AUST           ...                           99806.0
```

I need to pick a particular column ,lets say `wellthie_issuer_identifier`.

I need to query the database based on this column value. My select query will look something like .

```
select id, wellthie_issuer_identifier from issuers where wellthie_issuer_identifier in(....)
```

I need to add `id` column back to my existing dataframe with respect to the `wellthie_issuer_identifier`.

I have searched a lot but not clear with how this can be done.

Comment: what will be the value of id column when the condition doesn't match ?

Comment: I assume from table only those values will be returned which is there as I am putting it `IN` clause.

Comment: correct!! but you need to put ID column in exisiting df where there will be values of `wellthie_issuer_identifier` which are not considered in `IN` statement

Comment: we can put blank over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1.) **pick a particular column ,lets say `wellthie_issuer_identifier`**

`t = tuple(df.wellthie_issuer_identifier)`
This will give you a `tuple` like (1,0,1,1)

2.) **query the database based on this column value**

You need to substitute the above tuple in your query:

```
query = """select id, wellthie_issuer_identifier from issuers 
where wellthie_issuer_identifier in{} """
```

Create a Cursor to the database and execute this query and Create a Dataframe of the result.

```
cur.execute(query.format(t))
df_new = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
df_new.columns = ['id','wellthie_issuer_identifier']
```

Now your `df_new` will have columns `id, wellthie_issuer_identifier`. You need to add this `id` column back to existing df.

Do this:
`df = pd.merge(df,df_new, on='wellthie_issuer_identifier',how='left')`

It will add an `id` column to `df` which will have values if a match is found on `wellthie_issuer_identifier`, otherwise it will put `NaN`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi .. can you help me with this question pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949540/adding-a-new-row-to-a-dataframe-in-pandas-for-every-iteration

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another column to a dataframe using pandas if the column is not too long, For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('just.csv')
df

   id  user_id  name
0   1        1  tolu
1   2        5    jb
2   3        6   jbu
3   4        7   jab
4   5        9   jbb

#to add new column to the data above

df['new_column']=['jdb','biwe','iuwfb','ibeu','igu']#new values
df

   id  user_id  name new_column
0   1        1  tolu        jdb
1   2        5    jb       biwe
2   3        6   jbu      iuwfb
3   4        7   jab       ibeu
4   5        9   jbb        igu

#this should help if the dataset is not too much
```

then you can go on querying your database

Answer (score 0):

This will not take values for `wellthie_issuer_identifier` but as you told it will be all the values that are their, then below should work for you:

```
df1 = df.assign(id=(df['wellthie_issuer_identifier']).astype('category').cat.codes)
```

Comment: What is it actually doing ??

Comment: it is creating ID column based on unique value of `wellthie_issuer_identifier`, if the value is same, then ID is same