# Adding a new row to a dataframe in pandas for every iteration

Tags: python, pandas

[Adding a new row to a dataframe with correct mapping in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851042/adding-a-new-row-to-a-dataframe-with-correct-mapping-in-pandas/52851872?noredirect=1#comment92626118_52851872)

Something similar to the above question.

```
      carrier_plan_identifier           ...            hios_issuer_identifier
1                        AUSK           ...                           99806.0
2                        AUSM           ...                           99806.0
3                        AUSN           ...                           99806.0
4                        AUSS           ...                           99806.0
5                        AUST           ...                           99806.0
```

I need to pick multiple columns, lets say `carrier_plan_identifier`, `wellthie_issuer_identifier` and `hios_issuer_identifier`.

With these 3 columns I need to run a select query, something like ,

```
select id from table_name where carrier_plan_identifier = 'something' and wellthie_issuer_identifier = 'something' and hios_issuer_identifier = 'something'
```

I need to add `id` column back to my existing dataframe

Currently, I am doing something like this,

```
for index, frame in df_with_servicearea.iterrows():

            if frame['service_area_id'] and frame['issuer_id']:
                # reading from medical plans table
                medical_plan_id = getmodeldata.get_medicalplans(sess, frame['issuer_id'], frame['hios_plan_identifier'], frame['plan_year'],
                                                                frame['group_or_individual_plan_type'])

                frame['medical_plan_id'] = medical_plan_id
                df_with_servicearea.append(frame)
```

when I do this,`frame['medical_plan_id'] = medical_plan_id` , nothing is added. But when I do `df_with_servicearea['medical_plan_id'] = medical_plan_id` only the last value of the loop is added to all the rows. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

Update -:

After using , I am getting 4 rows , instead of 2 rows which should be there.

```
df_with_servicearea = df_with_servicearea.append(frame)



 wellthie_issuer_identifier       ...       medical_plan_id
0                   UHC99806       ...                   NaN
1                   UHC99806       ...                   NaN
0                   UHC99806       ...              879519.0
1                   UHC99806       ...              879520.0
```

Update 2 - Implemented based on Mayank's answer-
Hi Mayank , Is something like this you are suggesting.

for index, frame in df_with_servicearea.iterrows():

```
    if frame['service_area_id'] and frame['issuer_id']:
        # reading from medical plans table
        df_new = getmodeldata.get_medicalplans(sess, frame['issuer_id'], frame['hios_plan_identifier'], frame['plan_year'],
                                               frame['group_or_individual_plan_type'])
        df_new.columns = ['medical_plan_id', 'issuer_id', 'hios_plan_identifier', 'plan_year',
                          'group_or_individual_plan_type']
        new_df = pd.merge(df_with_servicearea, df_new, on=['issuer_id', 'hios_plan_identifier', 'plan_year', 'group_or_individual_plan_type'], how='left')

print new_df
```

my get_medicalplans function where I am calling the select query.

```
def get_medicalplans(self,sess, issuerid, hios_plan_identifier, plan_year, group_or_individual_plan_type):
    try:
        medical_plan = sess.query(MedicalPlan.id, MedicalPlan.issuer_id, MedicalPlan.hios_plan_identifier,
                                     MedicalPlan.plan_year, MedicalPlan.group_or_individual_plan_type).filter(MedicalPlan.issuer_id == issuerid,
                                     MedicalPlan.hios_plan_identifier == hios_plan_identifier,
                                     MedicalPlan.plan_year == plan_year,
                                     MedicalPlan.group_or_individual_plan_type == group_or_individual_plan_type)
        sess.commit()
        return pd.read_sql(medical_plan.statement, medical_plan.session.bind)
```

Comment: on what conditions do you want to add `id` back to your original dataframe?
Do these columns `carrier_plan_identifier, wellthie_issuer_identifier and hios_issuer_identifier` also exist in your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your issue is to change last row into:

```
    df_with_servicearea = df_with_servicearea.append(frame)
```

However, if you want to add new column, use:

```
df_with_servicearea['medical_plan_id'] = df_with_servicearea.apply(
    lambda row:
    getmodeldata.get_medicalplans(sess,
                                  row['issuer_id'],
                                  row['hios_plan_identifier'],
                                  row['plan_year'],
                                  row['group_or_individual_plan_type']
                                  )
    if row['service_area_id']
    and row['issuer_id']
    else np.nan)
```

Comment: It is giving me 4 rows of 2 rows which is not correct. Updated the question with output

Comment: @user1896796 Your question was unclear, how about now?

Comment: This is throwing error. I am not sure why .Is there anything simpler that can be done without using lambda maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Considering that you want to update the original df based on the below 3 cols:

1.) Tweak the query which you are firing on DB to include columns:`carrier_plan_identifier, wellthie_issuer_identifier and hios_issuer_identifier` in the `select` clause.

```
select id,carrier_plan_identifier, wellthie_issuer_identifier,hios_issuer_identifier from table_name where carrier_plan_identifier = 'something' and wellthie_issuer_identifier = 'something' and hios_issuer_identifier = 'something'
```

2.) Create a dataframe for the above results.

`df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())`

3.) Now above `df` has `id` column with the 3 other columns. Now, `merge` this `df` with the `original_df` based on columns : `carrier_plan_identifier, wellthie_issuer_identifier and hios_issuer_identifier`

```
original_df = pd.merge(original_df,df, on=['carrier_plan_identifier','wellthie_issuer_identifier','hios_issuer_identifier'],how='outer')
```

`Changed left join to Outer join.`

**So, you have to understand what's happening here. I am joining `query dataframe(df)` with the `original df` on columns carrier_plan_identifier, wellthie_issuer_identifier and hios_issuer_identifier and appending the `id` column as it was not present.
Wherever a match is found, `id` column's value from df will be copied to `original_df` and in case of no match, `id` column will have NaN. 
You don't have to use any loops. Just try out my code.**

This will add `id` column to `original_df` for all rows which match. For rows which don't find a match will have `id as Nan`.

You can replace `Nan` with any value like below:

```
original_df = original_df.fillna("")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am updated the question , Do you want me to call this within the loop?

Comment: First, please tell me the columns on which you want to add id to original frame? Then only I can hive you a proper solution.

Comment: I have a df lets say `[2 rows x 106 columns]` . I want to add an `id` column using the values of `carrier_plan_identifier, wellthie_issuer_identifier and hios_issuer_identifier` . These are there in my dataframe. A single select query is returning me multiple rows , but I can `LIMIT` it to 1. And then my final dataframe will have `[2 rows x 107 columns]`. If not , can you create a chat room where we can discuss. Would be of great help.

Comment: So, the output of your select query should be ingested in the dataframe, right? Here are 2 cases, `a)output of select query is already present in the dataframe` and `b) output of select query is not present in dataframe`. Check my updated answer.